# Laravel blade - access last element in collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have created a collection and passed to a view:

```
$tickets = Tickets::with('comments')->get();
```

I want to access the fields in the last reply and display the userid, an excerpt:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
...
<td>{{ $ticket->comments->last() }}</td>
...
@endforeach
```

The above works fine in that it returns an array of the last element, something like:

```
{"id":12,"body":"Close", ...}
```

All I am trying to do then is return the value of id, not the array.

I know it's something stupid I am overlooking, simplistically I was expecting this to work:

```
{{ $ticket->comments->last()->id }}
```

But it returns an error, of course, I expect that as I have already called last() there is nothing available to chain beyond that.

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

Can anyone advise how to return only the ID?  I will be suitably embarrassed with the answer I know it.  Just another one of those things I have looked so long at I can't see what I am missing.

Comment: can you show error?

Comment: {{ ($ticket->comments->last())->id ?? '' }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all when you say `{{ $ticket->comments->last() }}` it will return you serialized model instance. its generated in `__toString()` magic method. it converts php object into the string..

And here is tooString magic method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class

```
/**
 * Convert the model to its string representation.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->toJson();
}
```

---

`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

You're getting that error because some of your tickets doesn't have comment. So some of your comment relation of tickets return null, and you're trying to reach id property in `null` and that causes the above error

## SOLUTION

Best way to avoid this error is using `optional()` method which is perfectly fit kind of situation.

```
{{ optional($ticket->comments->last())->id }}
```

If comments relation doesn't have any item, it won't throw error.

Comment: I had thought of that and ensured every ticket that was part of the collection had at least one response.

Comment: @Holo I see, than can you update your question and share which error you're getting ?

Comment: @Holo well, I saw your update and... Can you try with my solution ? Because that error exactly happens in my situation. It says `trying to get property 'id' of non-object` meanwhile you're trying to retrieve a property from non-object data type which is probably `null`. I'm not sure but there might be little mistake in your tickets and some of them may haven't comment ?

Comment: Teoman, ffs... my fault.  Just checked the DB, one of the tickets had no reply! All working :) . Thanks for your time.  Will update yours as the answer.

Comment: @Holo I glad to help :) Also consider to use above helper. its really helpful and lifesaver when working with relations.

Answer (score 2):

If `last()` returns null then `->id` will throw error. You can use [`Null Coalescing Operator`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) in this case :

```
{{ $ticket->comments->last()->id ?? '' }}
```

Comment: As I noted above, last() does not return null, it correctly returns the last item, but as an array of the items.  ->id returns an error.  It would, as the element is returned as an array there is not further to chain through ->

Comment: Id you do `dd(gettype($ticket->comments->last()), get_class($ticket->comments->last()))` what do you get?

Comment: "object", "App\Http\Models\Comments"

Comment: Whats the exact error you are getting, can you paste it here please?

Comment: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: Thats strange. I think  thats happening on some other line in your blade and not on the one we are discussing now. Can you post the entire blade file? It will be easy to find it  that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188934/discussion-between-mihir-bhende-and-holo).